# AudioKit crackling after connecting headphones on iPhone 8+

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

We have an app, that uses AudioKit to record sound from the microphone and to playback it directly to your headphones.
If you connect your headphones to an iPhone 8+ after you started the app, it starts to crackle at the end of every recorded audioframe. If you do the same thing on every device older than iPhone 7 the app will work correctly.
If you plugged in the headphones before starting the app, it will work correctly in all scenarios, also if you plug in or plug off your headphones.

For better analysis I built a test-app, which only includes the audio-related functions.
This test-app behaves exactly like the other app.

We really have to fix this issue, because we have customers depending on the feature.

Any help in fixing this would be highly appreciated. AudioKit-version is 4.1.
We setup a github repository where you can checkout the code:
https://github.com/eskarion/audio-test

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for supplying the test project, only issue is I don't have an iPhone 8.  I can test on the X if you like.

Comment: Hi Aure,
thank you for your fast reply. This issue also happens on the iPhone X.

Comment: Okay, I can test on that.